# Defining the support of a random variable in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, regions, distributions

I wish to create a Mathematica module that would take as input a Mathematica-defined probability distribution D and will perform an integration over the support of its density f, $supp(f)$ (where $f:X\subseteq\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$). How to find the lower and upper bounds $s_1, s_2$ of the set:

$suppf=\left\{ x\in X:\,f\left(x\right)>0\right\} =\left[s_{1},s_{2}\right]$

For example, I am looking for a (perhaps already defined) Mathematica function such that if supplemented with UniformDistribution[{1, 2}] to return s1=1 and s2=2. Thank you for any inputs!

Comment: Have you already seen `DistributionDomain[]`? Look at e.g. `DistributionDomain[UniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]` and `DistributionDomain[NormalDistribution[]]`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! This function doesn't show up when I search in the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=DistributionDomain. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Ah, it looks like it's still undocumented... I've put in a link to a prior question.

Comment: Look at the documentation for [`Expectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) `Expectation` will do the integral and already knows the domain for the built-in distributions.